# Curly braces surrounding variable

Tags: perl, syntax

I have this piece of code that I'm trying to get my head around, I don't even know if its syntactically correct (part of the exercise I guess!)

```
%{$records}
```

What do the curly braces signify? I've seen the same case but with a `@` operator used instead of the `$` if that makes a difference.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 13):

The [“Using References” section of the perlref documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References) explains.

> **2.** Anywhere you’d put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type. In other words, the previous examples could be written like this:
>
> ```
>    $bar = ${$scalarref};
>    push(@{$arrayref}, $filename);
>    ${$arrayref}[0] = "January";
>    ${$hashref}{"KEY"} = "VALUE";
>    &{$coderef}(1,2,3);
>    $globref->print("output\n"); # iff IO::Handle is loaded
> ```

In your case, `$records` must be a reference to a hash (because of the outermost `%`), `{$records}` is a block that returns the reference, and `%{$records}` gives the original hash.

The curly braces surround a *bona fide* block. In fact, you could replace the code above with

```
%{ if ($records) { $records } else { $default_records } }
```

But even the shorter version from your question could be simplified, as pointed out earlier in the documentation.

> **1.** Anywhere you’d put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a simple scalar variable containing a reference of the correct type:
>
> ```
>    $bar = $$scalarref;
>    push(@$arrayref, $filename);
>    $$arrayref[0] = "January";
>    $$hashref{"KEY"} = "VALUE";
>    &$coderef(1,2,3);
>    print $globref "output\n";
> ```

Because `$records` is a simple scalar, `%$records` is the underlying hash.

If instead `$records` were a reference to an array, the syntax for dereferencing it would be `@$records` or `@{$records}`.

Answer (score 9):

In common with many Unix shells, Perl allows the use of braces to delimit variable identifiers, so `my ${scalar}` is the same as `my $scalar`. This is useful, for example, when interepolating the value of a variable into a string, when `"$scalartext"` will look for a variable with the identifier `scalartext`, when what is intended is `$scalar.'text'`. Instead of this you can write `"${scalar}text"` to get the correct result.

Perl will accept either a *bare* variable identifier or an expression returning a reference to a variable within the braces, so `%{$hashref}` is the same as `%$hashref`. Note that a *string* is unacceptable as it is treated as a symbolic reference which is an error under `strict 'refs'`, so `${'scalar'}` is wrong here.

In your case, `%{$records}` is identical to `%$records`, and some prefer it because it makes the dereferencing clear. It represents the hash to which hash reference `$records` refers.

Comment: It happens to be true that it works as a delimiter.  That's an intentional but accidental property.  The fundamental property is that the braces establish a BLOCK.  It is convenient, and part of the design, that the BLOCK's value can then be used by the surrounding expression without ambiguity about where the BLOCK begins or ends.

Comment: *"intentional but accidental"* is oxymorionic

Comment: No, it isn't, but I can see how one might think so.  Perl has a lot of behaviors that are both intentional and accidental; it's part of its strange consistency.  What I intended to convey is that while what you say is *true*, it ignores the reason *why* it's true.  If the word "accidental" bothers you there, maybe "intentional but not meaningful" will make more sense to you.

Comment: Oh, dear, no that's my mistake.  Of course "intentional but accidental" is oxymoronic.  I responded as though you said it was "oxymoronic and therefore false", which is of course a nonsense and not what you said.  I apologize.  The fact that it is oxymoronic, true, and also an example of itself is *why* I choose the phrase "intentional but accidental property" as part of a comment trying to explain why this answer is wrong lo those four years ago:  it delights me.

Comment: Late to the party but can I suggest a clearer way to say this? "It happens to be true that it works as a delimiter. That is intentional but it is only a side effect of the fundamental property. The fundamental property is that the braces establish a BLOCK."

Answer (score 5):

It is how you dereference a reference.

See [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

As usual the `%` or `@` states what sort of data you want ("A hash" or "An array").

This is followed by a *block* `{}` which returns a *reference* to the appropriate data type.

So: `%{$records}` takes a scalar (`$records`) containing a reference to a hash, and gives you back a hash.

Comment: It is simply a delimiter for the hash identifier, and is nothing to do with dereferencing. It is also *not* a block.

Comment: @Borodin — From the linked documentation: Anywhere you'd put an identifier (or chain of identifiers) as part of a variable or subroutine name, you can replace the identifier with a BLOCK returning a reference of the correct type

Comment: It is a very odd sort of block, as `${varname}` is fine, but `my $x = {varname}` is not. It is more like `my $x = do { no strict 'subs'; no warnings 'reserved'; varname };`

Comment: @Borodin Apples and oranges. Dereferencing uses *bona fide* blocks. The braces in the example above are from a syntactic alternative. From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors): “As in some shells, you can enclose the variable name in braces to disambiguate it from following alphanumerics (and underscores). You must also do this when interpolating a variable into a string to separate the variable name from a following double-colon or an apostrophe, since these would be otherwise treated as package separators”

Comment: @GregBacon: I may be wrong but I believe they are the *same structure*, as supporting `my ${var}` is pointless. I also think it's unlikely that the code to support symbolic references, like `${'var'}` is yet another meaning of a similar construct.

Comment: @Borodin There is no room here for opinions and probabilities. Perl accepts `my ${foo} = 1` just fine, but `my ${"bar"} = 2` generates a *parse error*. They are superficially similar in appearance, but the compiler generates different code for `${foo}`, `${"foo"}`, and `${$foo}`.

Comment: @Borodin: not a block? think at this `use strict; sub foo { \@{shift()} }; print "an year has @{ my $v = sqrt(144); foo([$v])} months";`