# How to copy a nested hash

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures, perl-hash

How to copy a multi level nested hash(say, %A) to another hash(say, %B)? I want to make sure that the new hash does not contain same references(pointers) as the original hash(%A).

> If I change anything in the original hash (%A), it should not change
>   anything in the new hash(%B).
>
> I want a generic way do it. I know I can do it by reassigning by value
>   for each level of keys(like, %{ $b{kb} } = %a;).

But, there should be a solution which would work irrespective of the number of key levels(hash of hash of hash of .... hash of hash)

**PROBLEM EXAMPLE**

```
use Data::Dumper; 
my %a=(q=>{ 
            q1=>1, 
            q2=>2, 
       }, 
        w=>2); 
my %b; 
my %c; 
%{ $b{kb} } = %a; 

print "\%b=[".Data::Dumper::Dumper (%b)."] "; 
%{ $c{kc} } = %a; # $b{kb} = \%a; 
print "\n\%c=[".Data::Dumper::Dumper (%c)."] "; 

# CHANGE THE VALUE OF KEY IN ORIGINAL HASH %a 
$a{q}{q1} = 2; # $c{kc} = \%a; 
print "\n\%b=[".Data::Dumper::Dumper (%b)."] "; 
print "\n\%c=[".Data::Dumper::Dumper (%c)."] ";
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: `$b{kb} = { %a };` is a bit more readable than `%{ $b{kb} } = %a;`. Being similar-looking to `$b{kb} = \%a;` makes it easier to contrast.

Comment: @ikegami Does curly brace(eg, `{ %a }`  get the reference (address) of a variable?

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for suggesting the improvement. Got an explanation at another [Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14911586/1443563)

Comment: `{ LIST }` is the hash constructor. It creates an anonymous hash, assigns the result of `LIST` to it, and returns a reference to the hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is commonly known as a "deep copy", where as the assignment operator does a "shallow copy".

```
use Storable qw( dclone );

my $copy = dclone($src);
```